# File scanner build in java

Tags: java, mysql, user-interface

file scanner - i scan a folder and hash(MD5) every file inside.
then i compare the hashes with my sql db which contain malicious file hashes.
If file(s) is malicious (hash(es) from my folder matches hashes in db) i want to append it to text area and delete it.

If file(s) is not malicious (files in my folder doesn't match any hashes in db) want to print in text area 'no malicious files found'.

problems:

1.as it is, if more than one file are malicious in my folder, the 1st file(hash) is printed twice.

2.if no malicious file are in folder the message 'no maliciuos files found' is not printed to text area.
3.I can delete the malicious file from folder but can't delete it from text area.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Here is my code

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
    if(e.getSource() == button){        
        int returnVal = fc.showDialog(AntiVirus.this, "MD5 Virus Check");
        if(returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){

            path  = fc.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath();

            File folder = new File(path);
            File [] filesList = folder.listFiles(); 

            // loop inside the folder and print the hash value      
            for (File selectFile : filesList){                  
                if (selectFile.isFile()){

                    areaMD5.append(checkSum(selectFile) + "\n");

                    String hash [] = areaMD5.getText().split("\n");

                    for (String hashFile : hash){

                        try{

                            final String queryCheck = "SELECT hashFileValue FROM hashfile WHERE hashFileValue = ?";             
                            final PreparedStatement ps = (PreparedStatement) conn.prepareStatement(queryCheck);                 
                            ps.setString(1, hashFile);                  
                            final ResultSet resultSet = ps.executeQuery();

                            while (resultSet.next()){

                                String hfv = resultSet.getString("hashFileValue");

                                if(hashFile.equals(hfv)){                                

                                   areaAnswer.append("     " + hashFile + "     " + selectFile.getName() + "\n");


                                   //delete file if malicious
                                   selectFile.delete();                                    
                                   areaDelete.setText("     File Name:     " + selectFile.getName() + "     was deleted ! \n");

                                }



                                //this statement doesn't work---------                          
                                else{

                                    areaAnswer.setText("   No malicious files found \n ");              
                                }


                             }// finish while

                           } catch (Exception ex){

                               areaAnswer.setText("Exception is: " + ex);
                           }    

                        }//end for loop

                    }//if(selectFile)

                }//for(File selectFile)

        }//if(JFileChooser)

        else{
            areaMD5.setText("   Select a folder. ");
        }

    }//if(e.getSource)

}//end actionPerformed
```

Comment: And you should split your code into classes and methods that have a clear, single responsibility, too, instead of mixing GUI, loops, string splitting and crypto together. If you need a comment after your curly braces, it's a sure sign that something is wrong.

Comment: I'd make sure that your query is returning something and that the text area you think you're updating is actually the one on the screen

Comment: Thank you guys for your replay... but I am not  a pro in java....I am trying to build a simple folder scanner, hash(md5) the files inside and compare them with hashes from mysql db.